# Can someone explain the body of the rest api to add users to groups?

Tags: rest, groups, user

Can someone explain this body to me? Multipart question to get to a single action (add).

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName' : 'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }
```

1. Specifically `'i:0#.w|domain\\user'`  what are literals and what are
   variables?
2. Is the 0 a literal or a user id?
3. Why `.w`? when I inquire /
   interrogate SharePoint our users come back .f, not .w!
4. For `|domain\\user`, is this a literal? If so how do you specify the
   actual user you are trying to add?
5. If  `|domain\\user`, is not a
   literal then was does it look like? `|ad.myuniversity.edu\\myuser`
   ... or ... `|ad.myuniversity.edu\\myuser@ad.myuniversity.edu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Claims Username Format

```
<IdentityClaim>:0<ClaimType><ClaimValueType><AuthMode>|<OriginalIssuer (optional)>|<ClaimValue>
```

Where:

```
<IdentityClaim> indicates the type of claim and is the following:
“i” for an identity claim
“c” for any other claim

<ClaimType> indicates the format for the claim value and is the following:
“#” for a user logon name
“.” for  an anonymous user
“5” for an email address
“!” for an identity provider
“+” for a Group security identifier (SID)
“-“ for a role
“%” for a farm ID
“?” for a name identifier
"\" for a private personal identifier (PPID)
"e" for a user principal name (UPN)

<ClaimValueType> indicates the type of formatting for the claim value and is the following:
“.” for a string
“+” for an RFC 822-formatted name

<AuthMode> indicates the type of authentication used to obtain the identity claim and is the following:
“w” for Windows claims (no original issuer)
“s” for the local SharePoint security token service (STS) (no original issuer)
“t” for a trusted issuer
“m” for a membership issuer
“r” for a role provider issuer
“f” for forms-based authentication
“c” for a claim provider

<OriginalIssuer> indicates the original issuer of the claim.

<ClaimValueType> indicates the value of the claim in the <ClaimType> format.
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-2013-claims-encoding-also-valuable-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I am going to accept this for the link more than the pasted part. It looks like I did get the answer needed. (If you are looking for specifics, the link is excellent and has additional information.)

Comment: There is no point in reinventing the wheel.. The pasted part is in future if the link goes down we have something to refer.. cheers!!!